# Get HTML from page outside of react comnponent

Tags: reactjs

I want to grab some html from the page outside of the React component and render it inside my component but I am not sure how to do this.

I tried:

```js
export default function App() {
  const image = document.getElementById("ext-image").outerHTML;
  console.log(image);

  return <div className="App">{image}</div>;
}
```

But it renders the HTML as a string instead of an HTML element.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: you can use the [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) prop. Note this would become `<div className="App" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: image}}></div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

```
export default function App() {
  const image = document.getElementById("ext-image").outerHTML;
  const imageHTML = {__html: image};

  return <div className="App" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={imageHTML} />;

}
```